# Formatting results in java

Tags: java

The following program code shows an example of how to format; both string as and numerical values ​​based on class `java.text.MessageFormat` . See the description class, and then adjust how the date format `rrrr-mm-dd`.

This is code:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Date;



public class FormattingResults {

public static void main(String[] args){

String s;

Date now = new Date();

String place = "Kraków";

int mile = 1852;

double tax = 0.22;
double price = 31560.76;

s = MessageFormat.format("{0}, {1,date,full}, time. {1,time,short}",
place, now);
System.out.println(s);

s = MessageFormat.format("{0}kB to {1}B", 256,256*1024);
System.out.println(s);

s = MessageFormat.format("{0} x {0} x {0} = {1}", 7, 7*7*7);
System.out.println(s);

s = MessageFormat.format("{0,number,currency} + tax({1,number,percent})",
price, tax);

System.out.println(s);

s = MessageFormat.format("{0} {1} it's approximately {2}m", 1,
"nautical mile", mile);
System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

In general, I do not understand this code , could someone help me solve a very easy task, for example:

```
"("{0}, {1,date,full}, time. {1,time,short}",
```

I read the oracle documentation, but sill don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MessageFormat use the current Locale to format dates.

Now if you want to change this format, you have to play with the FormatStyle paramter (the 3rd one);

Supported values are actually *short,medium,long,* and *full* far dates. Or you can use a custom patern.

```
MessageFormat.format( "{0}, {1,date,yyyy-mm-dd}, time. {1,time,medium}", place, now ); 
--> Kraków, 2016-04-19, time. 16:04:44

MessageFormat.format( "{0}, {1,date,mm-dd-yyyy}, time. {1,time,medium}", place, now );
--> Kraków, 06-19-2016, time. 16:06:39
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your program, that line printed:

```
Kraków, Monday, September 19, 2016, time. 3:52 PM
```

Next, I changed my computer’s language to Danish and ran again. This time I got:

```
Kraków, 19. september 2016, time. 15:54
```

Apart from two minutes having elapsed, you will notice that the date and time are now printed in Danish language and format, while before it was English. This is what MessageFormat.format() does: find the computer’s regional settings and apply them to the input.